# What is the smallest real number $m$ such that $n < m^n$ for all $n \geq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have taken a short look at this problem and found it to be much harder than expected to solve. Per the title, I am looking to find the *smallest* number $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the inequality $$n < m^n$$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb{R}$, $n \geq 1$. Using Python I was able to determine that $m\in [1.4446678610097, 1.4446678610098]$, suggesting the solution $m = e^{1/e}\approx 1.44466786100976\dots$. I assume this to in fact be the solution, and there there is a proof that I cannot come up with. Further research points to the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but the contents are beyond me at this point.

A solution/proof or explanation of this problem is appreciated.

Comment: There is no smallest such $m$. There is, however, a largest $m$ such that $n<m^n$ _doesn't_ always hold.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't see why such an $m$ cannot exist.

Comment: For any $m$ such that $m^n > n$ for all $n\geq 1$, there is another $m$ that is a little bit smaller. So there cannot be a smallest.

Comment: In jargon: you have to distinguish between **minimum** and **infimum** (or **greatest lower bound**). The latter is guaranteed to exist (as long as a lower bound exists at all, that is), but the former need not: consider "the smallest positive real number." In this particular case, there is no minimum but we can still calculate the infimum.

Comment: @Arthur and Noah Schweber thank you. I just blindly assumed a lower bound existed...

Comment: Oh, there are lower bounds ($m = 1$ is easily seen to be a lower bound, for instance). But no lower bound will actually fulfill the property you're asking about. The _largest_ lower bound, on the other hand (which is the $e^{1/e}$ that you suspected) will be such that any _larger_ number will be a valid $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, there is no smallest such $m$.  To see why $m = e^{1/e}$ doesn't work, notice that with $n=e$ we get $m^n = (e^{1/e})^e = e = n$.

However, if you're willing to ask instead about the smallest positive $m$ for which $n \leq m^n$ for all $n \geq 1$, then $m = e^{1/e}$ is indeed correct.  First, observe that with $m$ positive the inequality $n \leq m^n$ is equivalent to $\ln(n) \leq n\ln(m)$, or equivalently $\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \leq \ln(m)$.

You can now use calculus to prove that the absolute maximum of the function $f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ on $(0, \infty)$ occurs at $x=e$, and at that value $f(e) = \frac{1}{e}$.  Thus we should choose $m$ so that $\ln(m) = \frac{1}{e}$, which gives us $m = e^{1/e}$, as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're looking for a proof that the maximum value of $x^{\frac1x}$ for $x>1$ occurs at $x=e$.

Let $y=x^{\frac1x}$. Then $x\ln(y)=\ln(x)$. Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$, we get $$\ln(y)+x\cdot\frac1y\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1x,$$ which rearranges to $$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{\frac1x}\cdot\left(\frac1{x^2}-\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}\right).$$ The derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is equal to 0 for $x>1$ only at $x=e$, and we can confirm that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ indeed changes from positive to negative at $x=e$, thus proving that $y=x^{\frac1x}$ achieves its maximum value at $x=e$.

Then we have $$x^{\frac1x}\leq e^{\frac1e}\implies x\leq \left(e^{\frac1e}\right)^x$$ for all $x>1$.